# python lxml element attrib issue

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, lxml, xml-namespaces

I have to build a XML file that looks like the following:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<Document protocol="OCI" xmlns="C">
  <sessionId>xmlns=874587878</sessionId>
  <command xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="UserGetRegistrationListRequest">
    <userId>data</userId>
  </command>
</Document>
```

I got everything working except for the command attrib `xsi:type="UserGetRegistrationListRequest"`

I can't get the `:` in the attrib of the command element.

Can someone please help me with this issue?

I am using Python 3.5.

My current code is

```
from lxml import etree


root = etree.Element("Document", protocol="OCI", xmlns="C")
print(root.tag)
root.append(etree.Element("sessionId") )
sessionId=root.find("sessionId")
sessionId.text = "xmlns=78546587854"
root.append(etree.Element("command",  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",xsitype = "UserGetRegistrationListRequest"  ) )
command=root.find("command")
userID = etree.SubElement(command, "userId")
userID.text = "data"
print(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
tree.write('output.xml', pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True,   encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

and then i get this back

```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
   <Document protocol="OCI" xmlns="C">
   <sessionId>xmlns=78546587854</sessionId>
   <command xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsitype="UserGetRegistrationListRequest">
   <userId>data</userId>
 </command>
```

Comment: A [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will help us answer your question. However, having the `xsi:type` attribute without binding the `xsi` prefix to a namespace makes your XML not namespace well-formed. `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` would need to be `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QName` can be used to create the `xsi:type` attribute.

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.Element("Document", protocol="OCI", xmlns="C")

# Create sessionId element
sessionId = etree.SubElement(root, "sessionId")
sessionId.text = "xmlns=78546587854"

# Create xsi:type attribute using QName 
xsi_type = etree.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "type")

# Create command element, with xsi:type attribute
command = etree.SubElement(root, "command", {xsi_type: "UserGetRegistrationListRequest"})

# Create userId element
userID = etree.SubElement(command, "userId")
userID.text = "data"
```

Resulting XML (with the proper `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` declaration):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<Document protocol="OCI" xmlns="C">
  <sessionId>xmlns=78546587854</sessionId>
  <command xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="UserGetRegistrationListRequest">
    <userId>data</userId>
  </command>
</Document>
```

Note that the `xsi` prefix does not need to be explicitly defined in the Python code. lxml defines default prefixes for some well-known namespace URIs, including `xsi` for `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`.